# How can one type a box with "x" marked?

Tags: formatting, symbols

In some text portion of my notebook, I would like to be write check boxes which are empty, check marked or "x" marked.

The following commands work for the first two:

```
\[CheckmarkedBox]
\[EmptySquare]
```

But I am unable to find the command that would place an "x" inside the box.

Thanks.

Comment: `\[CheckedBox]`?

Comment: [`Text[Style["\[CheckedBox]", 40]]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qjsrB.png)

Comment: @J.M. and belisarius sweet! thanks. For whatever reasons I could not locate that in the special characters palette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach I took: I wasn't keen on searching within the *Mathematica* docs, but I already knew that [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2612/index.htm) offered a character for the box with an x-mark: `☒`.

So, I do this within *Mathematica*:

```
"☒" // FullForm
   "\[CheckedBox]"
```

which is what bel and me mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Ok, that's really helpful. Learning Fishing! Thx. :)