# How do I type boxtimes?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, fonts, customization

How do I type boxtimes in Mathematica, for example $a\boxtimes b$? This symbol is used a lot in mathematics, but I found no corresponding part in Mathematica. In TeX form, I can type \boxtimes.

Can I make one in Mathematica, and type it in a simple way, like the following?

```
\[EscapeKey]b*\[EscapeKey]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create some shorthand notation for a custom control?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15116/how-can-i-create-some-shorthand-notation-for-a-custom-control)

Comment: Perhaps that's not the best question to mark this as a duplicate of.  The solution is to create `InputAliases`.  See the answer I linked on how.

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs. Your link is very helpful, which answers my second question. There is the first question left, how do I create the symbol $\boxtimes$? Maybe I need to make a RowBox?

Comment: You can just paste it, or type it the same way you typed it here.  Usually, to find out the name of a named character, you can use `FullForm`.  For example, `FullForm[α]` will give you `\[Alpha]`.  `FullForm[⊠]` gives me `\:22a0`, which is just it's unicode character code.  So this particular character has no defined name in Mma.  It is possible that there is another character which looks very similar and has a name, but I haven't been able to find it [in the list](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html).  You can take a look too.

Comment: Thanks. When I type `\:22a0` I failed to get correct form $\boxtimes$. But I found a similar question [How can one type a box with "x" marked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22632/how-can-one-type-a-box-with-x-marked?rq=1).

Comment: What do you get when you type it?  Maybe Mathematica can't pull this character from a font that does have it.

Comment: The checkbox character differs clearly from the box times character.

Comment: When I typed `\:22a0`, I got an empty square which looks like `\[EmptySquare]`. When I apply `FullForm` to it, I do get `\:22a0`. So my Mathematica recognizes it, but can not display it correctly. Also, I tried `\:22a1` for the box dot $\boxdot$, and Mathematica displayed the same empty square.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the default font does not support this character and like OP I get `\[EmptySqure]` for each case.

As shown in [`Overlay/Applications`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Overlay.html) you can proceed with `\[EmptySquare]`, and `\[Times]`, but they do not seem to fit quite well. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey</kbd> to adjust positions or type it explicitly:

```
Overlay[{"\[EmptySquare]", 
         "\!\(\*AdjustmentBox[\"\[Times]\",BoxBaselineShift->-0.15]\)"}]
```

> [image]

Comment: +1. Did not know about `Alt`+`ArrowKey`. Very useful shortcut! I should visit the page [tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) more often.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the link, I was looking for it a second ago :p